# When does the program not call the destructor in c++?

Tags: c++, destructor

So here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C() {i = 6; cout << "A:" << i << endl;}

    C(int i0) {i = i0; cout << "B:" << i << endl;}

    ~C() {cout << "C:" << i << endl;}
private:
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "X" << endl;
    C *c = new C;
    cout << "Y" << endl;
}
```

For some reason the output for that code is

```
X
A:6
Y
```

And for some reason the destructor (C:6) is never called once you reach the end of the code. Why is that? Also this code does call the destructor:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C() {i = 0; cout << "A:" << i << endl;}

    C(int i0) {i = i0; cout << "B:" << i << endl;}

    ~C() {cout << "C:" << i << endl;}
private:
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "X" << endl;
    C c;
    cout << "Y" << endl;
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, you have to call `delete` for everything you call `new` on (note: not always true, but will hold for most cases)

Comment: C++ is no C#, avoid `new`

Comment: _When do you not call the destructor?_ Always. :)

Comment: @erip No, you don't call it, when you use new without delete - thats a pretty bad idea though.

Comment: @Anedar `delete` is NOT the destructor. `delete` destructs then deallocates memory.

Comment: Ok, then i am more specific: if you use a new without delete **or an explicit call of the destructor** - but as the OP showed you do not "always" call the destructor.

Comment: Well, you can't tell if the destructor is called or not because `c` is of type "pointer to `C`", and ordinary pointers don't have destructors. In the second piece of code, `c` is of type `C`, and `C` does have a destructor. So in one case, the object is of a type that has a destructor, in the other it's of a type that doesn't. No mystery there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you forgot to write

```
delete c;
```

If you just go on in your program without deleting a variable instantiated with new you will cause a memory leak.

**Edit, since you edited your question:**

If you write something like

```
C c;
C c{1};
C c = C{1};
```

you create a variable with automatic storage duration. It will run out of scope once the function it is declared in exits (or more precise: once the block it is declared in exits). In this case the constructor is called automatically.

If you write

```
C* c = new C{};
```

you create a pointer to a (new) C. The pointer itself has automatic storage duration, which means c will run out of scope as well. But the pointer only holds the adress of the object of type C. And this object is only deleted if you call `delete c;`. If you don't call delete, your program "forgets" the address of the object but it does not free the memory or destroy the object. That's a memory leak.
However once your program ends, all memory is freed (without calling destructors), so in your small example you wont notice.

Comment: But there's another code (that I posted up top) where I don't call delete c and that one called the destructor.

Comment: I expanded a bit about this.

Answer (score 5):

It's *very* rare that you need to directly call the destructor yourself.

The destructor is called automatically when an object is destroyed, either by going out of scope for a stack instance or by being `delete`d for a heap instance. So the fact that your destructor isn't being called tells you something: the object is being lost, or leaked.

`new` creates a new instance of the object from heap memory and opens a contract that, when the object is no-longer required, you will be responsible for calling `delete` to return it to the heap. (or `delete []` if you allocate an array)

In your code, you never `delete` the instance you created.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C() : m_i(6) { cout << "A:" << m_i << endl;}

    C(int i_) : m_i(i_) { cout << "B:" << m_i << endl;}

    ~C() {cout << "C:" << m_i << endl;}
private:
    int m_i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "X\n";
    C* c = new C;
    C stackC;
    cout << "Y\n";
    delete c;
    cout << "Z\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/iuZim4

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'new' to allocate a dynamic variable, the lifetime of the object instance ends with 1) delete or 2) process termination, or 3) system reset.

In your code, the program terminates before 'delete c;' is invoked, thus dtor is not invoked by the process.

Any dynamic memory used by the process is 'reclaimed' when the OS terminates the process. This OS 'Reclaiming' also does not invoke the dtor.

And when the system shuts down or is reboot, the software stops running, and thus does not invoke the dtor.

Allocating objects with no destructor invocation is common in embedded systems.